# Google-bigquery: Unable to find dataset: *********:analytics_******

Tags: google-bigquery

We are unable to see analytics dataset, while crashlytics dataset are visible in our project. While events are shown in firebase console.

[image]

[image: Please see in the image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765) a dataset is created in the BigQuery project upon the first daily export of events. Therefore, if there has been no export event, your dataset will not be available.